# Identification of an unusual tree

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Location : Lyon, France

[image]

I think it's one of the laziest trees I've ever seen XD

Comment: It looks like a cypress topiary. The form is most definitely not natural and trained to grow that way.

Answer (score 4):

As Sudachi has commented it has been pruned, probably over many years, to take on this form. It is not natural shape.

I would say that it is not possible to identify the exact species of tree without a close up of the leaves. From zooming in it looks like it could be a Lawson Cypress (*Chamaecyparis lawsoniana*) although it could be a Leyland Cypress (x *Cupressocyparis leylandii*), or a number of other possibilities.

One way to investigate this further if you want to know for certain, apart from posting a close up of the foliage which may help, would be to find some specimens of cypresses that you can find the name of. Perhaps in a garden centre or an arboretum, then compare the smell of the foliage when you pinch and crush it between your fingers. Different species have a characteristic smell that is a useful method for identification.